# CSS Slaint edges on bootstrap menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create [this](http://s16.postimage.org/6xshxdzhx/menu.png) in bootstrap with a menu, how would i get those slant edges in css?

Here's a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/BWM8c/) so far i have gotten one corner to be slanted, but i just cant seem to get another in the opposite direction.

Here's CSS i used for the on Edge:

```
    .navbar .nav {
        float: right;
        right: 0;
/*Slant Edges*/
        height:0;
        border-bottom: 40px solid #000;
        border-right: 40px solid white;
/*Slant Edges*/
    }
```

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would totaly use a `pseudo-element`

CSS:

```
    .nav-collapse:before {
    content:'';
        border-top: 40px solid white;
    border-right: 40px solid #000;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height:100%;
    width: 40px;
}
.nav-collapse:after {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height:0;
    border-top: 40px solid #000;
    border-right: 40px solid white;
}
.nav-collapse{
    padding:0 40px 0 0 ;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/BWM8c/5/

Comment: seems like a good solution but the edges need to be facing like "/-----/"(see image), I tried now but it freaks out...

Comment: @DawidvanderHoven Your example was facing that way so I did that the same way. I changed the answer and the fiddle, I believe it's ok now.

Comment: perfect, I know sorry my mistake.. Thanks A LOT!! for your help :) appreciate it.